# Style sheet issuewith blank lines

Tags: regex, ftp, dreamweaver

When i opened my style sheet using FTP, it seems lots of blank lines and white spaces.
how do i remove that, please help ..

an example line is here

uploaded css :

```
h1{
color:#01486d;    
font-size:42px;
} /* no blank lines  */
```

when i opened the same style sheet via FTP it is like

```
    h1    {
     color:#01486d; 

font-size:42px;



}/* lots of white spaces and blank lines */
```

some one suggest regular expression but i dont know how to use regular expression with dream viewer. 
please help 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up Vi/Vim, you can delete blank lines with the following code:

```
:g/^$/d
```

and tabs can be deleted with this bit of code:

```
:g/\t/d
```

Breakdown:

Hitting escape and then `:` will get you to the command prompt.
The actual command is `g/\t/d` 
The `g` searches the entire document
Everything in between the `/ /` is the regex pattern to look for, in this case lines lines that begin (`^`) with the end of line marker (`$`) and tabs (`\t`). The `d` represents the action to take. In this case, delete the line.

Comment: Thanks Paulo Calabro, you makes me smile

Comment: I didn't know about `:g`, only `:%s`

Answer (score 0):

Commands > Apply Source Formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression to find blank lines:

```
^$
```

Regular expression to find multiple blank lines in a row:

```
[\n]{2,}
```

You can just delete the first, or replace the second with `\n`.